# Why is a function that returns an int being reported as being of type a' -> int

Tags: f#

I have the following code, which reports errors. I don't understand the error messages though.

```
module MonochromeHandler

open System.Drawing

let private transparent = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0)

let private calculateAlpha currentAlpha greyValue =
    match currentAlpha - greyValue with
        | value when value < 0 -> 0
        | value -> value

let private actionPixel(pixelColour:Color) =
    match (pixelColour.A, pixelColour.R, pixelColour.G, pixelColour.B) with
        | (0uy, _, _, _) -> transparent
        | (alpha, red, green, blue) when red = blue && red = green && red <> 255uy ->
            let newAlpha = calculateAlpha((int)alpha, (int)red)
            Color.FromArgb(newAlpha, 0, 0, 0)
        | _ -> pixelColour
```

I am getting an error on the "`Color.FromArgb(newAlpha, 0, 0, 0)`" line

```
Error   1   This expression was expected to have type
    int    
but here has type
    'a -> int
```

The function takes two parameters, which I'm supplying and returns an int. So why isn't the type of newAlpha "`int`" and why is it "`'a -> int`"?

Possibly connected to this, since I have declared `calculateAlpha`without parentheses or a comma for the parameters, my (clearly inadequate) understanding of F# is that I should be able to use it thus:

```
let newAlpha = calculateAlpha (int)alpha (int)red
```

If I do that though, I get a different error for the `calculateAlpha (int)alpha` part:

```
Error   1   This value is not a function and cannot be applied
```

Why can I not invoke the function in this way?

Comment: You're not passing two arguments, you're passing a single tuple as an argument.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, to a degree. Since calculateAlpha is expecting an int for currentAlpha, why doesn't it report an error when I pass it a (int * int) tuple instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant

```
calculateAlpha (int alpha) (int red)
```

With your original parentheses, this line invokes calculateAlpha with 1 argument, and that argument is a 2-tuple:

```
let newAlpha = calculateAlpha((int)alpha, (int)red)
```

See the docs for [F# Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd233229%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), specifically *Partial Application of Arguments*. You will see how you inadvertently created the function `newAlpha`!

Comment: Ah, so (int)alpha isn't the correct way to cast to an int then? What does (int)alpha do then if not a cast?

Comment: `int` is a core function, not a C#-style cast. You are invoking this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee370576(v=vs.100).aspx. The parentheses add no meaning, `(int)` evaluates the same as `int`, which is called with `alpha` as the only argument

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. I am now marginally less ignorant about F#! :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'd write `int alpha` to cast an `int` in F#; technically, `(int)alpha` will work too but it's not the 'canonical' way of doing things. In any case, that's not the problem here.

The issue in your code actually arises from not surrounding the casts in parentheses; by not doing that, the F# compiler sees your code as if you'd written:

```
let newAlpha = (((calculateAlpha int) alpha) int) red
```

That's why you get the error message about expecting an `int` but having an `'a -> int` instead -- you're passing the `int` function (which casts some value to an `int`) as the first argument to `calculateAlpha`.

By surrounding your casts in parenthesis, you're telling the compiler to first cast the two values, then apply the results to the `calculateAlpha`. This is the same thing that happens when you call the function in your original style: `calculateAlpha ((int)alpha, (int)red)`; you could have even left off the parentheses around `int` there and written it like: `calculateAlpha (int alpha, int red)`.